# How do I implement std::io::Read for an Iterator<Item = String>?

Tags: io, iterator, rust

More specifically, I'm taking standard in, filtering out certain rows with `.lines().filter_map()` and I want to use the result of that with a `csv::Reader`.

Comment: This question came from the Rust IRC user "njoodle" in #rust on irc.mozilla.org, but it appears that the IRC logging wasn't working during that time so I can't provide a more complete authorship link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard library provides the type [`std::io::Cursor`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html) which wraps a buffer together with a position in the buffer.  This can be used to further simplify the code given in [Veedrac's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47610775/279627):

```
use std::io::{self, Cursor, Read};

struct IteratorAsRead<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
{
    iter: I,
    cursor: Option<Cursor<I::Item>>,
}

impl<I> IteratorAsRead<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
{
    pub fn new<T>(iter: T) -> Self
    where
        T: IntoIterator<IntoIter = I, Item = I::Item>,
    {
        let mut iter = iter.into_iter();
        let cursor = iter.next().map(Cursor::new);
        IteratorAsRead { iter, cursor }
    }
}

impl<I> Read for IteratorAsRead<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
    Cursor<I::Item>: Read,
{
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        while let Some(ref mut cursor) = self.cursor {
            let read = cursor.read(buf)?;
            if read > 0 {
                return Ok(read);
            }
            self.cursor = self.iter.next().map(Cursor::new);
        }
        Ok(0)
    }
}

#[test]
fn small_pieces_are_combined() {
    let iterable = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"];
    let mut reader = IteratorAsRead::new(&iterable);

    let mut buf = vec![];
    let bytes = reader.read_to_end(&mut buf).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(&buf[..bytes], b"hello");
}

#[test]
fn partial_reads() {
    let iterable = ["hello"];
    let mut reader = IteratorAsRead::new(&iterable);

    let mut buf = [0; 2];

    let bytes = reader.read(&mut buf).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(&buf[..bytes], b"he");

    let bytes = reader.read(&mut buf).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(&buf[..bytes], b"ll");

    let bytes = reader.read(&mut buf).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(&buf[..bytes], b"o");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8e3d082c3c496e681ae6ffc9aaa7142c)

Comment: There's an `impl<T> Read for Cursor<T> where T: AsRef<[u8]>`, so you don't even have to restrict the element type.

Comment: @Veedrac You are right, I would not need that restriction.  I mostly introduced it to avoid having to wrap the `Cursor` in an `Option`, but even then it can be made more generic again.

Comment: When using the default, the constructor should call `cursor.set_position(next.len())` to work with types where it is nonempty, like for statically sized arrays.

Comment: @Veedrac Oh, I did not think of that possibility.  I don't think I can use `len()`, though, since there is no trait for it, so I'd probably need to wrap the cursor in an `Option` again.

Comment: The slice has `len()`, so I could simply add `AsRef<[u8]>` to the constructor as well.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple implementation of `Read::read` if you allow it to return partial reads. Start with a similar structure to Shepmaster's.

```
use std::io::{self, Read};

struct IteratorAsRead<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
{
    iter: I,
    leftover: Option<(I::Item, usize)>,
}

impl<I> IteratorAsRead<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
{
    pub fn new<T>(iter: T) -> Self
    where
        T: IntoIterator<IntoIter = I, Item = I::Item>,
    {
        IteratorAsRead {
            iter: iter.into_iter(),
            leftover: None,
        }
    }
}
```

Then implement the function by first finding a nonempty string to read from, attempting to write it to the buffer, and finally storing any leftovers if need be.

```
impl<I> Read for IteratorAsRead<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: AsRef<[u8]>,
{
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        let (leftover, skip) = match self.leftover.take() {
            Some(last) => last,
            None => match self.iter.find(|next| !next.as_ref().is_empty()) {
                Some(next) => (next, 0),
                None => return Ok(0),
            }
        };

        let read = (&leftover.as_ref()[skip..]).read(buf)?;

        if skip + read < leftover.as_ref().len() {
            self.leftover = Some((leftover, skip + read));
        } else {
            self.leftover = None;
        }

        return Ok(read);
    }
}
```

Comment: I posted an even simpler version of this using `std::io::Cursor` – see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to read all the input at once into a giant buffer and then read from that:

```
let iterable = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"];
let combined_string: String = iterable.iter().cloned().collect(); 
let bytes = combined_string.into_bytes();

let mut buf = vec![];
let bytes = (&bytes[..]).read_to_end(&mut buf).unwrap();
assert_eq!(&buf[..bytes], b"hello");
```

If you really needed to avoid loading it all in memory, it's possible to implement a wrapper but it has some fiddly bits because the number of bytes available and the number of bytes to read won't always match up. You have to hold onto some temporary values to keep track of your position and sometimes get more data to continue reading from:

```
use std::io::{self, Read};
use std::cmp;

/// Eagerly consumes elements from the underlying iterator instead of
/// returning partial reads.
struct IteratorAsRead<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
{
    iter: I,
    value: Option<I::Item>,
    offset: usize,
}

impl<I> IteratorAsRead<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
{
    pub fn new<T>(iter: T) -> Self
    where
        T: IntoIterator<IntoIter = I, Item = I::Item>,
    {
        IteratorAsRead {
            iter: iter.into_iter(),
            value: None,
            offset: 0,
        }
    }
}

impl<I> Read for IteratorAsRead<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: AsRef<[u8]>,
{
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        let mut copied = 0;
        loop {
            match self.value.take() {
                None => {
                    match self.iter.next() {
                        None => {
                            return Ok(copied);
                        }
                        Some(value) => {
                            self.value = Some(value);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Some(original_value) => {
                    let entire_value_len = {
                        let entire_value = original_value.as_ref();

                        // Skip over bytes we already copied
                        let value = &entire_value[self.offset..];
                        let buf = &mut buf[copied..];

                        // Make the slices the same length
                        let len_to_copy = cmp::min(value.len(), buf.len());
                        let value = &value[..len_to_copy];
                        let buf = &mut buf[..len_to_copy];

                        // Copy
                        buf.copy_from_slice(value);

                        // Advance our values
                        copied += len_to_copy;
                        self.offset += len_to_copy;

                        entire_value.len()
                    };

                    // If we completely used the value, reset our counters,
                    // otherwise put it back for the next call.
                    if self.offset == entire_value_len {
                        self.offset = 0;
                    } else {
                        self.value = Some(original_value);
                    }
                }
            }

            // If we've filled the buffer, return it
            if copied == buf.len() {
                return Ok(copied);
            }
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn small_pieces_are_combined() {
    let iterable = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"];
    let mut reader = IteratorAsRead::new(&iterable);

    let mut buf = vec![];
    let bytes = reader.read_to_end(&mut buf).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(&buf[..bytes], b"hello");
}

#[test]
fn partial_reads() {
    let iterable = ["hello"];
    let mut reader = IteratorAsRead::new(&iterable);

    let mut buf = [0; 2];

    let bytes = reader.read(&mut buf).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(&buf[..bytes], b"he");

    let bytes = reader.read(&mut buf).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(&buf[..bytes], b"ll");

    let bytes = reader.read(&mut buf).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(&buf[..bytes], b"o");
}
```